# retrieving data from firestore using uid react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am super unfamiliar with react, but have this code below that I need to call the data from the database based on whoever it logged in. I have the uid being logged on that page, but not sure how to make that call to firebase with the specific uid.

```
 import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firestore = firebase.firestore();

class ProfilePage extends React.Component {
    state = {
        profiledata : null
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        firestore.collection('profiledata')
            .get()
             .then((snapshot) => {
                const profiledata  = []
                snapshot.forEach(function(doc){
                    const data = doc.data();
                    profiledata.push(data);
                }
                )
                this.setState({profiledata :  profiledata})
             })
             }
             
            render(){
        return(
            <div className='profile'>
                <h1>User</h1>
                {
                    this.state.profiledata && 
                        this.state.profiledata.map( profiledata => {
                            return(
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        First Name : {String(profiledata.firstname)}
                                        Last Name : {String(profiledata.lastname)}
                                        Company Name : {String(profiledata.companyname)}
                                                                        
                                        </p>
                                </div>
                                
                            )
                        })
                }
                </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ProfilePage;
```

right now this entire thing is returning all the users signed up in firebase. how do I change this to specifically call the users details based on the uid?

Comment: Hard to know without seeing your data structure, but it sounds like you want a specific document in a collection, so something like... `collection('profiledata').document(uid)`

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work. take a look here -> `firestore.collection('profiledata')             .doc("fbIIycHDpybMyjEJkNxUdAVqQr53").get().then((snapshot) => { `         I got the error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): snapshot.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Of course, you'll need to change the rest of your code to handle the document.  A `forEach` isn't going to work on something that isn't an array.

Comment: @jmargolisvt could you help me out with what to change... I honestly wouldn't know where to start. This is my first time using firebase as well

Comment: This has nothing to do with firebase once you've got the doc in hand.  You should add the data you get back from your call to your question if you need help dealing with it.  That should be basic JS, though.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I've never dealt with this type of thing before so that's where im confused... don't know what to change or how to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add .doc(uid) before the .get():

```
firestore.collection('profiledata')
  .doc(uid)
  .get()
  .then(doc => {
    console.log(doc.data());
  });
```

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work. take a look here -> `firestore.collection('profiledata')
            .doc("fbIIycHDpybMyjEJkNxUdAVqQr53").get().then((snapshot) => {         ` I got the error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): snapshot.forEach is not a function`

Comment: I think you mean `.doc(uid)` without the quotes.  Otherwise it will look for a doc literally named "uid".

Comment: I meant any uid with the quotes but I will edit. The result won't return a snapshot but the doc itself so you can replace your snapshot.forEach:
firestore.collection('profiledata').doc(uid).get().then(doc => console.log(doc.data()))

Comment: @VladimirVladimirov I've done what you mentioned about, it now loads the page, but it is loading no data and logging undefined :( I've replaced the function at whole with what you typed above, but logging undefined keeps happening. I've put the uid into the variable uid, and then put the variable uid as you did above, but still logging undefined